# Debugging Azure Queue Storage: how to view messages with a visibilityTimeout set in the future

Tags: c#, azure, queue

I am adding messages to queue storage that are set to be consumed in 24hours time by an Azure function but I have no way of knowing if the message is in the queue or not.

Is there a way to view the list of all messages (including ones with the visibilitytimeout set in the future) in the queue explorer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to view the list of all messages (including ones with
> the visibilitytimeout set in the future) in the queue explorer?

It is not possible to see the messages which are hidden (i.e. initial visibility timeout set in future).

To view the list of all other messages, you will need to dequeue the messages. It can get tricky because you can only dequeue only a maximum of 32 messages at a time. So if you have large number of messages and if you keep the `visibilitytimeout duration` of the dequeue operation small, you may end up dequeuing same message multiple times. Also, when a message is dequeued it becomes invisible to all other consumers of the queue for `visibilitytimeout` duration.

If you don't want to dequeue the messages, then you can only view top 32 messages in the queue.

Comment: I was thinking of using the Diagnostics tool to write to a storage account all read, writes and deletions. This should at least give me an idea if messages are being written even if I can't see them. What do you think?